# creating DCM report through google-app-script

Tags: google-apps-script

I am fairly new to Google App Scripts. I need to build report inside Spreadsheet using Google-app-script functionality. I know how to download from DCM/DFM reporting excisting report to spreadsheet.

But I've failed to create new inside spreadsheet without downloading existing report from DCM/DFM. Is it possible? May be somebody has a sample (I hadn't found)? Or I've missed the concept and the only way to pull data into Spreadsheet is to create the report in DCM/DCF Report Builder first?

Here is the code i'm using.

```js
function generateReport() {                                              
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Reports');
  var profileId = 2623334
  var httpOptions = {
        'headers': {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}
    }

  var resource = {
  
    'kind': 'dfareporting#report',
    'accountId': '34405',
    'type': 'STANDARD',
    'name': 'Simple Report',
    'criteria': {
    'dateRange': {
      'kind': 'dfareporting#dateRange',
      'startDate': '2016-09-01',
      'endDate': '2017-01-22',
    },
    'dimensions': [
      {
        'kind': 'dfareporting#sortedDimension',
        'name': 'dfa:date',
      }
    ],
   'metricNames': [
      'dfa:clicks', 'dfa:impressions'
    ],
  }
  }
  
  var url = DoubleClickCampaigns.Reports.insert(resource, profileId);
  var report =  UrlFetchApp.fetch(url.urls.apiUrl, httpOptions);  
  for (var i=0; i<report.length; i++) {
    var row = report[i];
    sheet.getRange('A' + String(i+2)).setValue(row[0]);
    sheet.getRange('B' + String(i+2)).setValue(row[1]);
    sheet.getRange('C' + String(i+2)).setValue(row[2]);
  }
}
```

The error appears here:

```
var report =  UrlFetchApp.fetch(url.urls.apiUrl, httpOptions);
```

Error Messsage:

> Can not read property "apiUrl" of undefined object.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Doubleclick api but it feels like `DoubleClickCampaigns.Reports.insert(resource, profileId);` is an asynchronous call that might not be finished by the time the script moves on trying to extract results.

Comment: FYI The report resource response object does not have a url property. https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-advertisers/v2.7/reports#resource

Comment: Thank you, finally I've sold the problem by 1) creating new report through google-app-script 2) downloading this report from DCM to Spreadsheet

Answer (score 0):

My final script is:

```js
function generateReport() {                                                 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Reports');
  var startDate = Browser.inputBox("Enter a start date (format: 'yyyy-mm-dd')");
  var endDate = Browser.inputBox("Enter an end date (format: 'yyyy-mm-dd')");
  var ReportName = Browser.inputBox("Enter your future report name");
  var profileId = 2623334; 
  var resource = {
    'kind': 'dfareporting#report',
    'accountId': '34405',
    'type': 'STANDARD',
    'name': ReportName,
    'criteria': {
       'dateRange': {
           'kind': 'dfareporting#dateRange',
           'startDate': startDate,
           'endDate': endDate,
                   },
       'dimensions': [
                       {
                         'kind': 'fareporting#sortedDimension',
                         'name': 'dfa:date'
                       }
                    ],
        'metricNames': [
      'dfa:clicks', 'dfa:impressions'
                       ],
                },
              };
  
  var httpOptions = {
        'headers': {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}
    }
  var url = DoubleClickCampaigns.Reports.insert(resource, profileId);                   //create Report inside DCM
  var newReportId = Number(url.id);  //get id of new Report  
  var additionalParameters = {
    'synchronous': 'true'
  };
  var newReportRun = DoubleClickCampaigns.Reports.run(profileId, newReportId, additionalParameters);          // run new Report in DCM
  var newReportFileId = Number(newReportRun.id);  //get id of New File
  var newReportFile = DoubleClickCampaigns.Files.get(newReportId, newReportFileId);     
    if(newReportFile.urls) {
      var httpOptions = {
        'headers': {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}             
      }
      var contents = UrlFetchApp.fetch(newReportFile.urls.apiUrl, httpOptions);              //Makes a request to fetch (получать) a URL using optional advanced parameters
      if(newReportFile.format == 'CSV') {                                                 
   
        var rows = Utilities.parseCsv(contents.getContentText());                                   
        if(rows && rows.length) {
          var fileName = "DCM_test_work5";
          var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.create(fileName);
          var sheet = spreadSheet.getActiveSheet();
          rows.map(function(r) { sheet.appendRow(r); });
        }
      } else {
      // Store the Excel file directly
        Logger.log('not CSV!');
        DocsList.createFile(contents.getBlob()).rename(newReportFile.fileName)
      }  
    }
}
```